# php strtotime is not showing the correct date

Tags: php, date, strtotime

I am trying to convert a date from my database into a different format, but for some reason it's not showing the correct time.

This is the date in the database:

```
17/06/2015
```

I'm using this code and its outputing this:

```
1970-01-01
```

This is the code I've tried so far, but as you can see it's outputting the incorrect date:

```
$date = str_replace('/', '-', "17/06/2015");
$date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime("17/06/2015"));

echo $date;
```

Comment: sidenote: you would have less problems if you were to use MySQL's functions to store dates (times) YYYY-mm-dd and will be easier to query. What you have now, seems to be saved as varchar/text/similar to.

Comment: true, but i need to find a way for this to work

Answer (score 0):

Try this I get the correct result from following code

```
$date = "17/06/2015";
$repDate = str_replace('/', '-', $date);
$newDate = date("Y-m-d", strtotime($repDate));
echo $newDate;
```